# true or false: if fn(x) is a decreasing sequence of functions and converges point wisely to f(x) then f(x) is a decreasing function

Tags: functional-analysis

i tried to use Dini's theorem to prove it converges uniformly but the question didn't say anything about its continuity, so f(x) might be discontinuous.
then i tried to find a counter example but all of them were decreasing
can you help me ? thanks

Comment: Just pick $x \leq y$, then $f_n(x) \geq f_n(y)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and if you take limits you get that $f(x) \geq f(y)$

Comment: @Eparoh, i think your answer is not complete.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: you mean the statement is true?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo and I prove it for increasing functions, but is the same argument. I fixed the typo and know is correct for what you were asking.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

False.
Let $f_n(x)=(1-x)^n$ for $x$ in $(0,1)$ and $n=1, 2, 3, ...$.
$f_n$ converges pointwise to the constant function $f(x)=0$.

Comment: but a constant function is neither decreasing nor increasing

Comment: Yes, the statement is false since the $f(x)$ is not necessarily decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

**This is false**

Taking $f_n(x)=x^2 +1/n$, the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ is decreasing and converges uniformly to $f(x)=x^2$. However $f$ is not decreasing.

Comment: the question is asking about pointwise convergence, the example you gave converges pointwisely to f(x)=0

Comment: No it converges pointwise to $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Limit as n-> infinity (x^2+1)/n equals 0 for all x belongs to R

Comment: @STalal  Can you read what I wrote correctly! Why do you invente parenthesis that I haven’t written???

Comment: ok i apologies!